# Why does this function return NoneType?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, user-defined-functions

```
def create(Type):
    if type(Type) == int:
        return 1
    if tyoe(Type) == str:
        return "String"

print create(int)
print create(str)  #both of these print 'None'
```

As I am not that experienced in python, I don't know too much, but this confuses me. It seems that this function *should* return their given types, however it returns None and I have no idea why.

Note: I need the `if type(Type)` part, so no golfing that away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `type(int)` is not `int`; it is `type`:

```
>>> type(int)
<type 'type'>
```

To test for a type, test *directly*, preferably using `is` as types are singletons:

```
if Type is int:
    return 1
```

but you'd be better of using a mapping here:

```
return {int: 1, str: 'String'}[Type]
```

If you are expected to use `type(something)`, then you should be passing in `int` or `str` **values**:

```
>>> type(1)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(1) is int
True
```

and not the type objects themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a type to the function, then taking the type *of that type*. So when you call `create(int)`, the function is taking `type(int)`, which is the type `type`, which doesn't match any of your if statements.